# ConvertPointFromView returning NAN

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to fill my scene with some SKSpriteNode objects. However, inside other views I'm already using these objects as UIImageView's. So I have the normal coordinates and I'm trying to convert to GL coordinates.

I'm doing it like this:

```
SKSpriteNode *title = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"labirinto_title"];
    CGPoint titlePoint = CGPointMake(238.0, 50.0); //coordinates already known.
    NSLog(@"X1: %f, Y1: %f", titlePoint.x, titlePoint.y);
    CGPoint titlePosition = [self convertPointFromView:titlePoint];
    NSLog(@"X: %f, Y: %f", titlePosition.x, titlePosition.y);
    title.position = titlePosition;
    NSLog(@"X: %f, Y: %f", titlePosition.x, titlePosition.y);
```

Then, the first NSLog is ok, however, the next two NSLogs are printing **NAN** for x and y values.

Anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I guess `self` is an `SKScene`.  I suspect that `self.view == nil` (meaning no `SKView` is currently presenting `self`).  The [documentation of `convertPointFromView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013024-CH1-SW17) says:

> The scene must be presented in a view before calling this method.